# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, networking, system, hyper-v

I'm trying to use this PS command to set an IP V4 Address to my VM

```
   $IPDNS1  = 192.168.10.10
    $DGMAINOFFICE = 192.168.10.254

    New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “ethernet” -IPAddress $IPDNS1 –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 
    $DGMAINOFFICE
```

but i receive this massage error

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress' because it is an empty string.
```

Comment: Get rid of the smart/curly quotes, `“ethernet”`, and replace them with dumb/straight quotes, `"ethernet"`. I might also suggest you use `$IPDNS1 = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.10"`, and `$DGMAINOFFICE = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.254"` too.

Comment: Did not really understand "replace them with dumb/straight quotes"

Comment: @Compo Perhaps best if you add this as complete answer?

Comment: @Compo you just wrote the same thing 
Get rid of the smart/curly quotes, “ethernet”
and replace them with dumb/straight quotes, "ethernet"

"ethernet" ???

Comment: And it still does not work .. @Compo

Comment: I cannot do anything whatsoever about the browser or font set that you're using for accessing this site, @ItayBeyder. But there is a clear difference in the web browser I'm using in OSX and also the one I'm using on Android, _(not just with my comment but with yours directly above this too)_. It may also be prudent to pay more attention to the rest of my initial comment too.

Comment: i changed the browser i see now the diff , but still same error

Comment: Have you modified your first two lines?

Comment: $IPDNS1 = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.10"
$DGMAINOFFICE = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.254"

New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "ethernet" -IPAddress $IPDHCP1 –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DGMAINOFFICE
            
ethernet - in dumb/straight quotes

Comment: … and what happens? Do you receive a message error, `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress' because it is an empty string.`?

Comment: @Compo exactly.

Comment: BTW, you dont have to use `[IPAddress]` you can simply doublequote your IP Address, in order that it is deemed to be a string. _(That'll be straight doublequotes, not the creative writing ones)_. `$IPDNS1 = "192.168.10.10"`, and `$DGMAINOFFICE = "192.168.10.254"`.

Comment: Did you make a typo in that comment? YES, _(you admitted to doing so)_, Should you therefore, have taken more care before hitting the the `[ENTER]` key, YES. Have I therefore said anything which was rude, or incorrect, NO. It appears that you want help, but have no inclination to read, assess, write, try, think, concentrate and feedback. None of those things are my fault.

Comment: @AngusY, it would be helpful to update your post with the current code you are trying. The original code you have posted makes sense that it causes an error because `$IPDNS1  = 192.168.10.10` stores nothing in `$IPDNS1`. You need quotes around the IP address.

Comment: @AngusY What Compo wrote was the problem with your question, I can make this more comprehensible if you like. Authors who write books and people who are typographic and like things to look good will use something called *smart curly quotes* which look like `“”` which if you can see are different than `""`. Languages do not use `“”` as valid object groupers since they are two different characters so you should always use `""` which are *dumb straight quotes*. Now like AdminOfThings is saying, `192.168.10.10` is not a valid expression, try turning it into a string with dumb straight quotes `""`

Comment: Variables in PowerShell are defined with *expressions* which means that anything you write into a variable, like `$var = "my word"`, `my word` will get written into the variable because the expression `"my word"` typed into the console will warrant you with the output of `my word` which will then get written to the variable. However, an IP like `192.168.10.10` typed into the console  will *not* have any output therefore nothing will get written to the variable. Try converting the miscellaneous value `192.168.10.10` that has no meaning to the console to something that does, `"192.168.10.10"`

Comment: `“”` and `""` may look similar,s o I understand your confusion, but in the console, they are completely different. That is why what @Compo said `“Ethernet”` and `"Ethernet"` are indeed different and not the same thing. This issue is relevant to the issue you are having as well. As you can tell, even `“` and `”` are different, one being a starting and ending quote so you may be able to tell this is trying to use 2 different characters to group something while `"` and `"` are the same character. `“”` aren't even on most keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my initial comment, *changing smart quotes to dumb quotes and defining the variable type*:

```
$IPDNS1 = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.10"
$DGMAINOFFICE = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.254"
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias "ethernet" -IPAddress $IPDNS1 –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DGMAINOFFICE
```

You stated that this didn't work, so let's try to determine why!

Open a PowerShell Prompt, and take a look at the help information for the command, `Get-Help New-NetIPAddress`, you should see the types of data your command expects to receive. `[-IPAddress] <String>` and `[-DefaultGateway <String>]`. So lets take a look at what type it was defined as. Type, and enter the following `$IPDNS1 = [IPAddress] "192.168.10.10"`, now follow that up with the following command `$IPDNS1.GetType().Name`. You should see that the defined type is `IPAddress`, not `String`, so let's try to fix that:

Type, and enter the following `$IPDNS1 = [String] "192.168.10.10"`, now follow that up with the following command `$IPDNS1.GetType().Name`. You should see that the defined type is correcly identified as `String`. so let's try that for real:

```
$IPDNS1 = [String] "192.168.10.10"
$DGMAINOFFICE = [String] "192.168.10.254"
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias "ethernet" -IPAddress $IPDNS1 –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DGMAINOFFICE
```

It should be noted however that the default/standard way to define a variable as a string type is to just doublequote it, *(not smartquotes)*, as I also mentioned in the comment section:

To test it enter `$IPDNS1 = "192.168.10.10"` at the Prompt, followed by `$IPDNS1.GetType().Name`, you should see that the type is `String`, so lets see that translated to your command:

```
$IPDNS1 = "192.168.10.10"
$DGMAINOFFICE = "192.168.10.254"
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias "ethernet" -IPAddress $IPDNS1 –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DGMAINOFFICE
```